# Uninstall R from Mac OSX 10.9.2

Tags: r

How do I uninstall R from my MacBook Pro OSX 10.9.2?

I need to reinstall a later version (The version for the Mavericks operating system.)

Sincerely
Joe Mark

Answer (score 57):

In the "R Installation and Administration" manual says next:

> If you want to get rid of R more completely using a Terminal, simply
>   run (prepend sudo if needed):

```
rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/R.framework /Applications/R.app \    
/usr/bin/R /usr/bin/Rscript
```

If be exactly, from that point:

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Uninstalling-under-OS-X

[UPD: updated link to R uninstalling section](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Uninstalling-under-macOS)

Comment: Link-only answers are not ideal. Perhaps edit to include the important points from the link.

Comment: The link will probably stay more up to date than the answer -- the command has been changed there to reflect installation at `/usr/local`