# How to uninstall R completely from OS X

Tags: r, uninstallation

I'm on Mac OS X 10.11.5, R version 3.3.1

I followed the instructions to remove R:

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Uninstalling-under-OS-X

In command line:

`sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/R.framework /Applications/R.app \
   /usr/bin/R /usr/bin/Rscript`

I no longer see R in applications or anywhere else on my computer. However, I am still able to run R from the command line.

I am mystified. What is going on? How do I get rid of R completely? I want a fresh start.

Comment: Have you tried using `where` to locate it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `where`. I tried `whereis R` and nothing happened.

Comment: I also tried `find R` and I get `No such file of directory`, yet I can still run R from command line. I don't get it!

Comment: Try `which R` as well as `where R`

Comment: I was able to find location with `which R`. Thank u!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uninstall R from Mac OSX 10.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981581/uninstall-r-from-mac-osx-10-9-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `which R`. It will give you the location where R is running so that you can remove it from there.