# updating both Rprofile and R to the same version

Tags: r, bash, macos, version, rprofile

Is there any idea, how I can find the version of my Rscript? 
The issue is, once I am running R in mac terminal, the version is 3.2.2 but running via Rscript the version is changed to 3.0.2. I would like to know how to update my Rscript's version!

Comment: Difficult to see how this could occur, without knowing the specifics of your local system. Perhaps you have installed R twice, once using Homebrew and again from the official package?

Comment: I see but is there any way to update the latest version of Rprofile ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `Rprofile` is a configuration file. There's a site-wide file for the current version of R; there may also be a per-user version `.Rprofile` if you created one.

Comment: Unclear how this could happen. You need to tell more about your system and `R`. You can edit an `.Rprofile` with a text editor; it is just a text file.

Answer (score 0):

*I cannot comment, because I have less than 50 rep, so I'm writing here.*

Are you under macOS Sierra?

When I upgraded R to version 3.4.0 after upgrading my Mac to macOS 10.12 (Sierra) I had some problems with rJava. While I searched for a solution, I also noticed that the R version numbers displayed in the GUI and the terminal differed. I am not quite sure what that problem was, but part of my solution was to [completely uninstall R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390548/how-to-uninstall-r-completely-from-os-x) (note the comments about using `which R` !).

Comment: Thanks for the comment and sorry for not being clear in my post. My problem was solved by changing the directory for Rscript in the same way as R directory. I found that I have 2 separate directories that R run in one of them (3.2.2) and Rscript run in the other one (3.0.2). So I changed my bashrc to:
 
`alias R="/usr/local/r-3.2.2/lib64/R/bin/R"` 

`alias Rscript="/usr/local/r-3.2.2/bin/Rscript"`