# Anaconda installation of R interfers with regular R installation?

Tags: r, cran

Probably a very basic question for someone who knows what they're doing.

I installed anaconda and jupyter notebooks, and now `which R` returns `/opt/anaconda3/bin/R`, rather than `/usr/local/bin/R` as it did before.

How do I change this back so that RStudio uses `/usr/local/bin/R`, but preferably without deleting files, editing `PATH` environment variable, or moving files/binaries around (I am open to suggestion, but prefer a 'best practice' so that anaconda/notebooks work if I need them).

Comment: Did you try `export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/local/bin/R`?  See https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-RStudio-desktop.

Comment: @H1 I quick fixed it by removing the anaconda R binaries with `rm $(which R)` and `rm $(which rscript)`, then [uninstalling regular R entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24981651/5783745) and RStudio entirely, then reinstalled R + RStudio. Amateur fix. It worked, but the anaconda version obviously won't work anymore. I will definitely try `export` when I can, I have bookmarked the link you provide, looks like excellent reading (I wasn't even aware of the order in which RStudio scans for R until seeing it there) - thanks very much for the knowledge